# gcc link error:cmake cross compile can't find secondary libraries even if the rpath is set using cmake

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, cross-compiling

I'm trying cross compile arm program which depends on lots libraries. Explicit include the lib*.so can solve this but its not decent and in my project is almost impossible.

simplified problem is like below, e.g.

```
mainexe -> libcv_highgui.so(founded) -> libjpeg.so(missing)
```

but at linking time, i got error:

```
ld: warning: libjpeg.so.8, needed by /opt/tkfs/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.10, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

I have added rpath, and I checked ./build/CMakeFiles/mainexe.dir/link.txt, rpath is already there:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++   main.cpp.o   -Wl,-rpath,/opt/tkfs/:/opt/tkfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf /opt/tkfs/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.10 -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/tkfs/usr/local/lib
```

here is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(testopencv)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS "ON")
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(ROOTFS_DIR          "/opt/tkfs/")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  "arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc")

set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH              FALSE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH      TRUE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH   TRUE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  
    ${ROOTFS_DIR}
    ${ROOTFS_DIR}/usr/lib/
    ${ROOTFS_DIR}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    )
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${ROOTFS_DIR};${ROOTFS_DIR}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf;${ROOTFS_DIR}/opt/ros/indigo/lib)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM   NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY   ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE   ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE   ONLY)
#set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${ROOTFS_DIR}/")
find_package( OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui)

add_executable( main src/main.cpp )

target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

env:

- all ld_library_path is set to empty;
- 3 gcc version is identical 4.8.4(host, cross compile, arm dev board)
- both machine is ubuntu 14.04.
- all libs like libjpeg.so.8 are in $rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf

Comment: *Cross-compilation* normally involves [toochain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux) file, where all cross-compilation aspects (*CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME*,  *CMAKE_C_COMPILER*, *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH*, etc.) are set. Setting some of this aspects in `CMakeLists.txt`, especially after `project()` call, doesn't have desired effect. Also, it seems that value of 
 your *ROOTFS_DIR* variable should be assigned to [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) variable instead of *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH* one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks alot, your suggestion really helped a lot. but when I use CMAKE_SYSROOT, I got another error: `#include <algorithm>`, cannot found this file, this is cpp libs, but I don't know how to include it decent, if I use `include_directories()`, things get mass again...

Comment: Update your question post with information about your toolchain.